# Remove :focus on :active

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm looking for a way to remove an element's :focus when it becomes :active.

I've got a navbar that toggles between 3 anchors when the user scrolls, firing off the anchor's :active.

When the user clicks the anchors the browser smoothly transitions the scroll to the anchor's reference. 
The problem is that the focus persists after the user scrolls. Meaning that I might have one anchor in :focus and one in :active.

My intent is to have the :focus removed as the :active hits the element.

I've not been able to find anything on Google regarding this issue, most of the questions people have been asking is how to remove the `outline` of items.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: black;
}
.navbar-nav>.active>a {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
#navbar {
  margin: 12px 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9vw 10vw margin-top: 8vw;
  margin-right: 15vw;
  margin-bottom: 8vw;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1vw solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4vw;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.nav>li {
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #722872;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.nav>li a:hover {
  color: #722872;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar-target" class="navbar-toggle">
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar-target">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="#top"> About </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#portfolio"> Portfolio </a>
      </li>
      <li class>
        <a href="#contact"> Contact </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Outline is simply `outline: none`, but why don't you delete all CSS on `:focus` and only have CSS for `.active` and `:hover`? Btw, do you have a Bootply?

Comment: Well, it does seem as if the bootstrap navbar has some predefined color schemes firing off when events are triggered...
Even if I remove the :focus it defaults back to some predefined background color when I trigger the anchor's :focus. :/

Comment: Did you try `:active:focus` selector?

Comment: I have not. But it does seem like there are specific events-triggers in navbar seem to be needed to be overridden to make it work as I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this was handled by adding this simple jQuery snippet:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
  $(this).blur();
});
```

This allows me to override the :hover and when the anchor gets clicked the above snippet gets fired off, making the click *'transparent'* whilst allowing the :active (scroll) to be above it.